# Building opnMPI on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, openmpi

I am currently building `openmpi-3.1.2` on Cygwin. I finished configure stage and now try to make it with the `make` command. But I am constantly getting this warning: `fd_set and associated macros have been defined in sys/types.      This can cause runtime problems with W32 sockets` and then the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:57,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/event.h:63,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent2022.h:58,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/event/event.h:76,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/pmix/pmix.h:24,
                 from ../../../opal/util/proc.c:22:
/usr/include/w32api/psdk_inc/_ip_types.h:25:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct hostent’
 struct hostent {
        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/Semen/openmpi-3.1.2/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/include/event2/util.h:67,
                 from /home/Semen/openmpi-3.1.2/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/evutil.h:37,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/event.h:57,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent2022.h:58,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/event/event.h:76,
                 from ../../../opal/mca/pmix/pmix.h:24,
                 from ../../../opal/util/proc.c:22:
/usr/include/netdb.h:79:8: note: originally defined here
 struct hostent {
```

My GCC configuration:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.3.0-3.x86_64/src/gcc-7.3.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.3.0-3.x86_64/src/gcc-7.3.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC)
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: why don't you simply use the openmpi package provided by Cygwin ? note cygwin patches the embedded libevent library and you want to do that too. An other (untested) option is to use the external libevent `configure --with-libevent=external`. Last but not least, note the latest Open MPI version is `3.1.3`.

Comment: libevent external does not work (yet) on cygwin. I strongly suggest any way to use the openmpi cygwin package as @GillesGouaillardet is also suggesting

Comment: My problem is that I need to not only be able to use OpenMPI compiler wrapper inside of the Cygwin, but also to use it manually in Windows. In particularly I need is to be specified in my PATH to use it while building the Boost library.

Comment: Concerning @GillesGouaillardet suggestion, there is exactly the same issue with openmpi-3.1.3.

Comment: Not clear what you mean with `use it manually in Windows`. If you are doing a Cygwin build it will work as the available Cygwin binary package.

Comment: I want to build Boost library with the mpicc compiler wrapper. It is stated on the Boost official [web-site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html#mpi.mpi_impl), that it is not tested with MSMPI. So I decided to use OpneMPI for that purpose. Is that possible to do this with the package I can install in Cygwin?